# Azure CI Pipeline does not discover any tests once I have multiple 'TargetFrameworks'

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, azure-devops

Here's the relevant part of my C# library csproj file

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net46;net48</TargetFrameworks>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
```

As the question states, my Azure CI build pipeline completes successfully, but I'm noticing that the *Test* task in my pipeline takes only 1 second - and that is due to the discovery of any 'test' .dll's is failing to find anything.

I am quite certain that it's due to my outdated test DLL discovery paths

```
**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
!**\obj\**
```

The above is what USED to work, when there was only 1 target framework moniker.

Now that I'm trying to support multiple frameworks, I am wondering if there's a slick way to indicate that by tweaking these discovery paths (some type of wildcard technique that I can use everywhere, across different Azure DevOps projects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered that there is no magic discovery path that really works

My old pipeline was using [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) from the days when it was a traditional .NET Framework application

When I changed my .csproj to conform to the new SDK format (even though I was still building .NET Framework apps) I should have changed to a different type of task for doing the tests...

Changing to [dotnet test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive#run-your-tests) did the trick. It has a different approach. Instead of wanting paths to compiled DLLs, it starts by wanting a pattern to help it find the PROJECT file

[image]